# Are any Apollo Launch Mission Rule Documents available for downloading?

Tags: apollo-program, history

Apollo **Flight** Mission Rule Documents (from JSC) are easy to find on the internet, but the **Launch** Mission Rule Documents (from KSC) - not so much.

I found a couple paper copies for sale, but that's not what I want.

[image]

([image source](https://historical.ha.com/itm/transportation/space-exploration/apollo-11-nasa-launch-mission-rules-sa-506-csm-107-lm-5-book-in-original-grumman-binder/a/6037-41098.s))

Are there any pdfs of these documents available for download?  (I want one from a crewed Apollo mission.)

Comment: I doubt it because they're selling it in an auction meaning it's probably rare. But I'm looking.

Comment: I've done a lot of research asking and answering Apollo questions, and have not come across such documents (or even bibliography references to them).

Comment: @StarMan: I'm not convinced of such an argument.  The guidance computer source code is available on-line, yet I'd be willing to pay big bucks for an original printout.  (Even more if it was autographed by Margaret Hamilton.)

Comment: @Organic Marble Are you looking for that **exact** copy?

Comment: @StarMan No, I'll take any LMRD associated with a manned Apollo flight.

Comment: @DrSheldon The FMRDs reference the LMRDs.

Comment: I sent a request to the STI for document 630-23-0002 (Apollo/Saturn Launch Mission Rules Handbook), so we'll see what comes of it

Comment: You could of course submit a FOIA request (https://socialforms.nasa.gov/foia), but that usually isn't free.

Comment: @AshPera Let's hope the Launch Mission Rules *Handbook* is not a document that tells you how to work with the LMRD, but I fear it might be.

Comment: @Organic Marble the fine folks at STI couldn't seem to find a copy of it :/

Comment: @AshPera bummer. I'll try and contact one of the rapidly dwindling number of people I know at KSC.

Comment: @OrganicMarble   This Google search: apollo "launch mission rules" site:www.hq.nasa.gov comes up with nothing close to what you want...